# Geting rid of extra 'b' in changing binary format to base64

Tags: python, api, soap, binary, base64

I've got a strange problem. I'm using one of EBI SOAP services and I'm running three iterations. At first iteration I have no problem in running my code because variable 'selectedHits' is empty. At the end of first iteration I update variable 'selectedHits' and then change it to binary form and then to base64 format (because this variable must be in base64 format). This is a part of my code:

```
jobID=''; selectedHits=''
for e in range(1,4):
    inputparam = client.factory.create('InputParameters')
    inputparam.scores=5
    inputparam.alignments=5
    inputparam.previousjobid = jobID
    inputparam.selectedHits = selectedHits

    response = client.service.run('Info@gmail.com',name,inputparam)
    jobID=response
    selectedHits=str(base64.b64encode(bytes(selectedHits, 'utf-8')),'utf-8')
    #print(selectedHits)
    #print(response)
```

Imagine that our new selectedHits is as follows:

```
b'U1A6RlJEQ19FQ09MSQpTUDpGUkRDX1NISURTClRSOkQyVE1CM19DSVRSSQpTUDpGUkRDX1NBTFRZClRSOkQ0QkZKMV85RU5UUgo='
```

when I use this new 'selectedHits' at the second iteration, instead of getting the result I get 'Info@gmail.com' repeatedly!!!  when I manually eliminate character 'b' at the first part of this new 'selectedHits', I'll get result. When I try to eliminate character 'b' automatically by different ways (here by using the following code):

```
selectedHits=str(base64.b64encode(bytes(selectedHits, 'utf-8')),'utf-8')
```

, I mostly don't get the result and I'll get error (In summary as follows):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)
raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(5228 bytes read)
```

I'm confused and don't know exactly what to do. When I eliminate 'b' automatically, I don't get the result. When I retain this 'b' character, I don't get the result too!! just by eliminating the character by hand and using the following value for selectedHits, I'll get the answer:

```
'U1A6RlJEQ19FQ09MSQpTUDpGUkRDX1NISURTClRSOkQyVE1CM19DSVRSSQpTUDpGUkRDX1NBTFRZClRSOkQ0QkZKMV85RU5UUgo='
```

I should mention that I'm writing my code in python 3.6.

I searched over stackoverflow and found a lot of ways to get rid of this extra 'b', but they weren't effective in this case and the problem didn't get solved.

I would like to know if anyone has any idea to help me for solving this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you are just trying to convert the bytes literal into a string?

Comment: when I convert it to string, I get error. I just need to introduce 'selectedHits'  variable in base64 format to the second iteration. No difference if it is string or binary. I just want to get answer...

Comment: What are you trying to implement with `str(base64.b64encode(bytes(b64, 'utf-8')),'utf-8')`?

Comment: First I needed to make it binary by using   bytes(b64, 'utf-8')   and then change it to base 64 with  base64.b64encode(bytes(b64, 'utf-8'))    and then  
 str(base64.b64encode(bytes(b64, 'utf-8')),'utf-8')    for getting rid of extra 'b'.

Comment: I think I need to retain 'selectedHits' variable in a binary form and base 64 while eliminating extra 'b' without changing the variable to string. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: I don't get how do you actually update `selectedHits` via iterations since it starts from `selectedHits=''` before the loop and then you update it only in `selectedHits=str(base64.b64encode..` - so it looks like never changes and should stay as an empty string. Where `b'U1A6RlJEQ1...` format comes from?

Comment: This is just a small part of my code... The whole code works in a right way and updates. 'selectedHits' will get full during running the complete code. It was a usual text file that I changed it to base64 and got  b'U1A6RlJEQ1...

Comment: First it was  'SP:FRDC_ECOLI\nSP:FRDC_SHIDS\nTR:D2TMB3_CITRI\nSP:FRDC_SALTY\nTR:D4BFJ1_9ENTR\n'   that after changing to base 64, I got  b'U1A6RlJEQ1...

Comment: What is the output for `#print(selectedHits)` just under the line you update `selectedHits`?

Comment: The output is  b'U1A6RlJEQ1...

Comment: It shouldn't since you use `str(..., 'utf-8')` and the output must be `<str>` - without prefix `b`. Check it again, please

Comment: Sorry. You are right... the answer is  'U1A6RlJEQ1...

Comment: Is there any difference between the `U1A6RlJEQ1...` string from updated `selectedHits` and the version when you eliminate the `b`-prefix by hand? Try to `print(repr(...))` for both of these strings

Comment: Yes. you are right... it seems they are different. The string form created by the above code is U1A6RlJEQ1... but the one eliminated by hand is 'U1A6RlJEQ1...' None.     It seems that it remains binary after eliminating 'b' by hand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158125/discussion-between-maximtitarenko-and-sara).

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a kind of server issues...Last night I tried the following and I got answer:

First I thought that all of these errors were for the sake of a mistake at initialization of 'selectedHits':

```
selectedHits=  ''
```

We said that selectedHits must be in binary and base 64 format; So initializing value must also be in a binary form; So we made the initialization 'selectedHits' to binary form as we did at follows:

```
selectedHits=''
selectedHits=base64.b64encode(bytes(selectedHits, 'utf-8'))
```

I also changed the code for getting final 'selectedHits' to:

```
selectedHits=base64.b64encode(bytes(selectedHits, 'utf-8'))
```

All of that problems and errors were solved... but today I tried it again and instead of getting the result, I got a lot of Email addresses typed!

I tried to change the 'selectedHits' to binary and then base64 and then again to string both at initialization and update (at the end of the code) and I got the right answer so I think it was mostly a kind of server issues rather than technical programming mistake.

Thanks